# UnicodeDecodeError after restart on server

Tags: python

I've implemented a product called Odoo/OpenERP and recently performed a restart after changing some strings in multiple files.

These strings contained standard characters with no accented characters. After the restart, any access to the site results in the below:

```
2015-06-24 08:09:35,884 1584 ERROR XXXXXX-Odoo-Production werkzeug: Error on request:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)

File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/service/server.py", line 290, in app
return self.app(e, s)


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
result = handler(environ, start_response)


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/http.py", line 1290, in __call__
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)


File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response)


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/http.py", line 1426, in dispatch
ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/http.py", line 346, in registry
return openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(self.db) if self.db else None


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 339, in get
update_module)


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 356, in new
registry = Registry(db_name)


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __init__
self._db = openerp.sql_db.db_connect(db_name)


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/sql_db.py", line 623, in db_connect
db, uri = dsn(to)


File "/opt/odoo-production/openerp/sql_db.py", line 614, in dsn
return db_or_uri, '%sdbname=%s' % (_dsn, db_or_uri)


UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've checked the files I've made changes to, but these seem fine.

Does anyone know where I can start to debug this issue? I'm relatively new to Python and debugging/understanding this trace is something I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Have you tried `utf8` encoding?

Comment: Where exactly am I defining the use of `utf8`? This is the main difficulty I'm having is tracing the source, or am I misunderstanding your statement?

Comment: Update: Checked all mentioned .py files in the above trace, all of them have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of them

Answer (score 0):

So you have to use `unicode` strings because when your string is processed, somewhere it needs to use it as `unicode`, and it fails because the string type is `str`. You can make it into unicode by

```
mystring = unicode(mystring, 'utf-8')
```

This will change the type of your string from `str` to `unicode`

Comment: Hey there Naman, thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is I have no idea which file is causing the problem. Any ideas how I can actually find the source file having the issue?

Comment: I cannot tell this until I see the full code, just make sure that whenever your string is processed, it has to be passed as unicode.